# IIS Logs not capturing all requests

Tags: .net, api, logging, iis-10

I am trying to find a way to associate IIS logs with logs that are generated within my .NET API code. What I am finding, however, is the IIS logs do not seem to capture every incoming request. I did a stress test of my API, which made roughly 12000 requests to the API hosted in IIS, but the IIS logs only seemed to capture around 800 of them.

I have not been able to find anyone else with a similar problem, so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or am I just expecting too much out of IIS logging?

Any commentary on my original goal of associating IIS logs with my api logs is welcome, as that isn't going well either.

Comment: You can get some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863661/will-all-requests-that-appear-in-httperr-logs-also-appear-in-the-iis-logs-by-de

Comment: Did you gain any additional insight to share regarding this?  I've discovered the same thing - I know the request happened and exactly when, because it got recorded in my database, but it is *not* in the IIS logs and I'm trying to figure out if this is potentially a clue for the intermittent issue I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: At some point I was told that IIS only logs requests that are complete. In my case I had some bad code where a request would generate a thread, and there were conditions where the thread could enter an infinite loop.  So since the request never completed or failed, the request was never logged. And the infinite loop was perceived my as a memory leak for quite a while, which could be easily rectified by restarting the iis app. All the threads would die and nothing would get logged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS logs requests after they have completed. W3WP.exe logs to memory after the response has been sent to the client. Then at regular intervals W3Wp.exe writes to the IIS log file specified in the Website configuration. You may have to wait several seconds before requests are visible in the IIS log file. I believe that HTTP.sys is written to in realtime. If you don't see your requests in the IIS log file, check that you are indeed visiting the website you think you are. You can also check the most recent %systemroot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR log file for your request, if IIS can't handle your request, HTTP.sys will log why IIS could not accept the request. Hope this can help you.

Comment: This actually helped me find some lost requests, thanks!